Difference between みな様に知ります and みな様を知ります
What’s the difference in meaning between みな様に知ります and みな様を知ります, and are they both grammatical?
Can に be used with 知ります in this manner?

Minor correction: When used on its own as an adverb, you say みんか, but when it’s used with さん or 様, you just say みな (i.e. みなさん and みなさま). At least, that’s what my dictionary says :-)

@JoshGrosso meant みんな*

Aを知ります is correct, and means "will learn A" or "will get to know A". However, Aに知ります is not a correct usage of the verb 知る.
Also note that みんな様 is not a valid phrase to say "everyone". Maybe you wanted to say みなさま (皆様)?
